# How get access the unmodified body of a Fastify request

Tags: node.js, typescript, stripe-payments, fastify, zod

i'm using Fastify server with Zod validation schema, I aim to access the original, unaltered body of a Fastify request specifically to verify a signature in a webhook. Essentially, I want to examine the request in its initial state, unaffected by any middleware.
, this is my code :

```
    import { z } from "zod";
    import { ZodFastifyInstance } from "@shared/types";
    
    export const checkout-Webhook = (server: ZodFastifyInstance) =>
      server.route({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/api/webhook",
        schema: {
          headers: webhook_Schema,
        },
        async handler(request, reply) {
          const sig = request.headers['stripe-signature'];
          const body = (request.body as string);
      
          await this.checkoutService.tryCrediUser(body, sig);
    
          return reply.code(201).send();
        },
      });
    
    
    const webhook_Schema = z.object({ "stripe-signature": z.string() });
```

i get an error with this code:
StripeSignatureVerificationError: Webhook payload must be provided as a string or a Buffer (https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) instance representing the *raw* request body.Payload was provided as a parsed JavaScript object instead.
Signature verification is impossible without access to the original signed material.

I've used fastify-row-body but the rawBody is **undefined** ?  :

```
import { z } from "zod";
import { ZodFastifyInstance } from "@shared/types";
import rawbody,{ RawBodyPluginOptions } from 'fastify-raw-body';
import fp from "fastify-plugin";

export default fp<RawBodyPluginOptions>(async (fastify) => {
  fastify.register(rawbody, {
    field: "rawBody", // change the default request.rawBody property name
    global: false, // add the rawBody to every request. **Default true**
    encoding: false, // set it to false to set rawBody as a Buffer **Default utf8**
    runFirst: true, // get the body before any 
preParsing hook change/uncompress it. **Default false**
    routes: ['/api/webhook'], // array of routes, **`global`** will be ignored, wildcard routes not supported
  });
});

export const checkout-webhook = (server: ZodFastifyInstance) =>
  server.route({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/api/webhook",
    config: {
      rawBody: true
    },
    async handler(request, reply) {
      const sig = request.headers['stripe-signature'];
      const body = request.rawBody ;

      await this.checkoutService.tryCrediUser(body, sig);
      return reply.code(201).send();
    },
  })
```

Comment: I did a plugin for this reason https://www.npmjs.com/package/fastify-raw-body

Comment: i use it, but i get rowBody undefiend , why ?

Comment: I can't know it without seeing the code

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this problem by adding preParsing hook :

```
 
import { z } from "zod";
    import { ZodFastifyInstance } from "@shared/types";
    
    export const checkout-Webhook = (server: ZodFastifyInstance) =>
      server.route({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/api/webhook",
        schema: {
          headers: webhook_Schema,
        },
       preParsing(request, reply, paload, done) {
           request.headers['content-type'] ='text/plain'
           done();
        },
        async handler(request, reply) {
          const sig = request.headers['stripe-signature'];
          const body = (request.body as string);
      
          await this.checkoutService.tryCrediUser(body, sig);
    
          return reply.code(201).send();
        },
      });
    
    
    const webhook_Schema = z.object({ "stripe-signature": z.string() });
```